# Bouncing images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make some images "bounce".

http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/43/

```
$('#bbb').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().effect('bounce',500);
});
$('#bbb').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true);
});
$('#target').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().effect('bounce',500);
});
$('#target').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true);
});
$('#sears').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().effect('bounce',500);
});
$('#sears').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true);
});
```

```
<div id="RegStores">
    <a href="http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/regGiftRegistry.asp?wrn=-1824276933&amp;" target="_new"><img src="http://www.dkg2012.com/img/bbb.png" id="bbb" width="144" height="48" border="0" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.target.com/RegistryGiftGiverCmd?isPreview=false&amp;status=completePageLink&amp;listId=HCoY5fRCrcOOxRCdNn3i6g&amp;registryType=WD&amp;isAjax=false" target="_new"><img src="http://www.dkg2012.com/img/target.png" id="target" width="143" height="34" border="0" style="padding-left: 10px; padding-bottom: 5px;" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.sears.com/shc/s/GRManageView?storeId=10153&amp;catalogId=12605&amp;langId=&amp;externalId=900040792636010101&amp;grUserType=BUYER&amp;fwdURL=GRGuestRegistryView&amp;sortType=category" target="_new"><img src="http://www.dkg2012.com/img/sears.png" width="142" height="40" border="0" id="sears" style="padding-left: 10px;" /></a>
</div>
```

```
#RegStores {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:23px;
    width:467px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:30;
}
```

How can I get this to work **without** making the other images move down. And also, when you run your mouse over an image rapidly it causes the image to keep moving up and up - how can I fix that?.

Comment: It seems like `effect bounce` changes the style of the element in such a way that it pushes the other elements down (maybe `display: block`?)

Comment: @tandu: Placing **disply: block;** in the CSS did not change the overall problem.

Comment: I was able to transfer the code from jsfiddle into your post for you, please try to do so in the future. Sometimes jsfiddle has outages and the links are unavailable, and many of us do not need a live demo to spot problems in code, so the extra step of opening a new tab is a little annoying.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/45/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I meant in my comment was that the animation is doing that (i.e. adding `display: block`) .. actually it's not really adding that in and of itself, but it wraps the item to animate in a div.  You can add `.ui-effects-wrap { display: inline-block; }` to fix this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/46/

However, this will only work in browsers that support that, so you may have to use floats instead.  You should also probably use a more specific rule (e.g. wrap all of that in its own div) so you don't impact other effects that use that class.  Ideally, jQuery would have a way to change the wrapper class as well.  I can't imagine that it doesn't..

EDIT: After being castigated by Good Guy Greg for not answering all parts of the multipart question, I created an update here:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7UjD/47/

This will prevent the image from animating on hover while it's already animating.  Personally, this is most desirable for me, but if you want to stop the animation on mouse out (doesn't make sense to me) or again on mouseover, you will have to do something else.

Comment: Well beat me to it - here is a fiddle with your suggestions. Also switched up to using hover instead of mouseenter/leave which built up too many events. http://jsfiddle.net/EcN2h/

Comment: The OP wrote "when you run your mouse over an image rapidly it causes the image to keep moving up and up." This seems like a fairly serious issue, and this answer completely ignores it.

Comment: Yes.. any fix for the rapidly causing the image to keep moving up?

Answer (score 3):

Here is one that mostly fixes the ability to drive it up to the top. I do this by animating ti back down to its starting position on mouse out. Also made some other improvements. Notably switching to `hover` and applying a class to each of the links instead of using a separate event binder for each.

http://jsfiddle.net/EcN2h/2/

```
$('.bounce').hover(function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true, true).effect('bounce', 500);
}, function() {
    $('img', this).stop(true, true) );
});
​
```

​

Comment: @StealthRT - actually this is even better. The push effect is from the link animating, but calling `stop` in the mouseover causes it to eventually end up misplaced. By calling the event on the link, animating the image itself, then we don't get the nasty pushing effect. http://jsfiddle.net/EcN2h/2/

Answer (score 1):

This is a suggestion. I'm putting it here as it would not look pretty in comment

```
$('#bbb,#target,#sears').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().effect('bounce',500);
});
$('#bbb,#target,#sears').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).stop(true,true);
});
```

You can shorten your code like this.